# how to install SMTP server on xampp

Tags: php, email, smtp

i want to send mail via php mail() function.
now i need to install SMTP server on my computer for this one work.

i donwloaded the hMailServer, but i dont know what i need to setup there.
also, what i need to setup in the php.ini file?

i read some tutorials while searching google, but didnt work for me.

i dont want to use phpMailer with Gmail SMTP server, i want to send it from the SMTP server that found on the server.

also, before i was tried to setup send mail in php.ini, maybe i change there somthing and now i need to change it back, so i dont know what to change back, please tell me all things that i need to define for hMail will work...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: @chandresh_cool , i dont want to use sendmail with gmail SMTP server...